# How do I convert an object array to an object list

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following structure :

```
[
   {
     "key": "Asset Type",
     "values": ["Appliances", "Electronics"]
    }, 
    {
      "key": "Asset Availability",
      "values": ["In Stock"]
    }
]
```

I need to convert it to :

```
{
  "Asset Type": ["appliances", "electronics"],
  "Asset Availability": ["in stock"]
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one approach using [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) and [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (to transform the array into 2d-array since that's what the [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) expect)

```js
const items = [{
    "key": "Asset Type",
    "values": ["Appliances", "Electronics"]
  },
  {
    "key": "Asset Availability",
    "values": ["In Stock"]
  }
]

console.log(
  Object.fromEntries(items.map(({
    key,
    values
  }) => [key, values]))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the simplest solution I found

```
const items = [
    {
     "key": "Asset Type",
     "values": ["Appliances", "Electronics"]
    }, 
    {
      "key": "Asset Availability",
      "values": ["In Stock"]
    }
]
let output = items.map((obj)=>{
    let result = {};
    result[obj.key] = obj.values;
    return result;
    });
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution is using Array.prototype.reduce() method

```
const array = [
  {
    key: 'Asset Type',
    values: ['Appliances', 'Electronics']
  },
  {
    key: 'Asset Availability',
    values: ['In Stock']
  }
]

console.log(
  array.reduce((acc, rec) => {
    acc = { ...acc, [rec.key]: rec.values }
    return acc
  }, {})
)
```

Comment: `acc = { ...acc, [rec.key]: rec.values }` - why introduce this complicated destructuring, which will cause the object to be reconstructed every time? `acc[rec.key] = rec.values` has the same effect and is shorter and more readable

Comment: I agree with you.